# In Windows 8, does passing object between pages pass their reference or a copy of them?

Tags: c#, reference, windows-8, pass-by-reference

I have the following scenario:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Visibility = false;
img.Source = "..some path here..";
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Photos), img);
```

upon navigating to the new Photos page, I'm passing the `image` object I just created.

Would this new `image` object be passed as a copy of the original object, thus allocating some more memory, or would this object continue on to the new page as a reference?

If this won't pass as a reference - how would you implement this? moving an object along the lifecycle of my app from page to page without having to recreate it each time?

Comment: Creating a copy/clone isn't defined for all types. Therefore, it cannot be a copy. What would it mean to copy a message box or a FileStream? Makes no sense.

Comment: You cannot "pass" an "object" in C#. Objects are not values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Image is a reference type, a reference is passed.

I suggest reading a C# beginner book front to end - the concept of reference types is core fundamental to the whole design of the language.